# Notification sound not stopping android

Tags: android, android-notifications, notificationmanager

> I simply call a Notification . But It continuously playing sound unless I drag notification ..

Below is my code and right now I am testing on below OREO..

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "droidudes.zcode";

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String name = "easyTouch";
            String Description = "Best Utility Tool";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;//IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            mChannel.setDescription(Description);
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mChannel.setVibrationPattern();
            mChannel.setShowBadge(false);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                mContext, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                ///.setVibrate(longArrayOf(0, 1000, 500, 1000))

                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_of_app)
                .setContentTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("Toucher Hiding Here")
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 1,
                new Intent(mContext,EasyTouchService.class)
                        .setAction(EasyTouchService.ACTION_SHOW), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        Notification mNotification = mBuilder.build();

        mNotification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        //mNotification.tickerText = getString(R.string.app_name);
        // setUpAsForeground(message);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
```

I have tried multiple ways by commenting vibration sound in above code . But still sound play for unlimited time..

Answer (score 0):

***Try this out:***

```
 final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                mCtx,
                notfication_id,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
        final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mCtx);
                Notification mNotif = builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logo)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setContentTitle("title of your notification")
                        .setContentText("details of your notification")
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mCtx.getResources(),R.drawable.logo_full))
                        .build();

                mNotif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                mNotif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                mNotif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;


                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)mCtx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify((int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE), mNotif);
```